# Hamilton-Jacobi theory vs Hamiltonian formalism

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I'm writing some notes on Hamilton-Jacobi Theory and I'd like to find an example of a system that is quite difficult to integrate in the usual Hamiltonian formalism, but quite easy in the Hamilton-Jacobi theory. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: FWIW, there are many Hamiltonian systems with action-angle variables but where the trajectories (as a function of time) are only known numerically.

Comment: I'd like to find an example that is elegant and easy to understand, but at the same time it's not trivial...